# propagating target-specific variables in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a makefile with target specific variables that are used in prerequisites as follows

```
SOURCES = a.c b.c

.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.o: %.c
    @echo gcc -o $@ $<

1: SOURCES += main_1.c
1: obj

2: SOURCES += main_2.c
2: obj

obj: OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))
obj: build

build: $$(OBJECTS)
    @echo gcc -o exe $(OBJECTS)
```

Of course in my code `$(SOURCES)` is only `a.c b.c` and `$$(OBJECTS)` is empty … and if I write `$$(SOURCES)` I get an error that there is `No rule to make target $(SOURCES)`.
Is there any way to make this work ? or will I have to define variables to switch between 1 and 2 ? (something like `make -D1` with a `#ifdef`)

Comment: Your makefile as posted here works fine for me, GNU make 3.81.
Perhaps this example doesn't capture the problem?

Comment: Strange … when I run this makefile, the `OBJECTS` variable is empty at the `build` step, and the rule `%.o` is never called. I'm also using GNU Make 3.81

Comment: My apologies, you are quite right! I just looked at the "link" output.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to say `1: OBJECTS += main_1.o`?

Comment: the reason why I'm doing it this way is in my actual makefile I'm using a common general `objdir/` directory for all objects, an I want to avoid redundancy if possible. And this would not solve the problem anyways as `OBJECTS` would be defined in rule 1 and would not propagate to the prerequisites of `build` ...